# Adding Search Button to UINavigationBar : Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a ViewController1 and ViewController2. ViewController1 has a NavigationController set to it. I have a button (Custom Search Icon) on the NavigationBar. Now I press control+click and drag to ViewController2 and set it to Show. When I press it, it doesn't work. I also tried to drag the button to ViewController1 and set it as an IBAction but that doesn't work either.

What I want accomplished:
I want to create a button on the left side of the NavBar. When clicking it, I want to be add the searchbar and allow the user to search from an array. What is the best way about doing this? The search bar also has the cancel button, and if pressed the user should return back to his previous ViewController. I don't want anyone to the work for me but if you could point me to the right direction, it would be awesome.

Comment: By "Custom Search Icon" do you mean UIBarButtonItem? In what way does it not work when you try to connect to an IBAction in ViewController1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by "Custom Search Icon", you mean a `UIBarButtonItem` in the navigation bar. If that's the case you *should* be able to segue to a controller using the technique you described, so you could try putting in a new `UIBarButtonItem` and try again.

But for the problem you're describing I might recommend a slightly different approach using `UISearchController`. Since it sounds like you're using storyboards, drag in the **Search Bar and Search Display Controller** from the object library to your controller, just below the navigation bar.

Check out UISearchController documentation:
[https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/ ]

And here's a sample project from Apple:
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html ]

Good luck!

Comment: I try to go on the sample project link however it says its "Page not found"

Comment: It included the brackets in the URL, now it will work.

Comment: Got it, Thanks. My problem was that I was using ImageView instead of a Button. I will follow apples guidelines in creating the searchbar option instead of working from scratch. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the connections from the interface builder first. Clear the codes associated to the button.
Create an IBAction and put a break point to see if its called when u click the button.
If it does get called then push a new ViewController onto it,(ViewController2).
Add your search bar here on the ViewController 2.

Comment: I found my main error, I was using ImageView instead of a button. Am I on the right path to creating a search mechanism? How do I put a searchbar in the navigationBar?